# How to fix the problem with If statement used 3 times?

Tags: java, if-statement

The task is this - *Print "Positive", "Negative" or "Zero" depending on the value of n.* I can write the positive and negative part with if, but not the last "zero" part. If I  write 0 and then press spacebar, "zero" is shown. But If I write only 0, it gives me error.

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
        int n = sc.nextInt(); 
        if (n>0) {
            System.out.println("Positive");
        } else if (n<0) {
            System.out.println("Negative");
        } else if (n == 0); {
            System.out.println("Zero");
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get ? (oh, and just a little remark: if it is neither positive, nor negative, it is necessarily zero, so no need for a last `else if`: an `else` would be sufficient).

Comment: If you had used a good IDE, it would have warned you about your extraneous `;` problem, and you'd have saved the time of everybody, especially your own, so please start using an IDE instead of a simple text editor to write code.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra semicolon in you code

```
// ...
} else if (n == 0); {  // <---- HERE
    System.out.println("Zero");
}
```

This means the block of code is not dependent on the `if`. In fact, the `if` is trying to run an empty statement.

Remove the semicolon or just remove the condition altogether. After all, if an integer is neither less than, nor greater than zero, it must be zero.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
        int n = sc.nextInt(); 
        if (n>0) {
            System.out.println("Positive");
        } else if (n<0) {
            System.out.println("Negative");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Zero");
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
}
```